# UI no renderiza en la build pero si en el editor unity

Tags: unity3d, unity, unity2d

Tengo un problema con la UI de unity cuando no es "Screen space- Overlay" es decir cuando es "Screen space-Camera" o "World Space" todo parece funcionar perfectamente en el editor pero no aparece nada cuando hago la build

Comment: Puedes poner parte de tu código para verificar que problema se te presenta, has tratado de poner un punto de interrupción para verificar lo que esta realizando el código?